# How to use layers with blocks and columns?

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

I have on my frame two columns. First with three items and second withh three blocks:

```
\begin{frame}{myFrame}{subtitle}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1->item 1
    \item<2->item 2
    \item<3->item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\end{column}
    \begin{column}<1->{.6\textwidth}
        \uncover<1->{
            \begin{block}<1->{Block1}
              Text in block 1.
        \end{block}
        }
    \uncover<2->{
        \begin{block}<2->{Block2}
          Text in block 2.
        \end{block}
     }
    \uncover<3->{
        \begin{block}<3->{Block3}
          Text in block 3.
        \end{block}
     }

\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

The effect I would like to get is when on the first layer only first item and block 1 is active, and other are grayed. On second leyer first and second item and block active and third grayed. On third layer everything active.

That what I have now don't work. On first layer blocks 2 and 3 are invisible, on second and third blocks appear but they're greyed and only on the last layer they become active.

I have used `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`

Please help. :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6):

To get that particular effect, do not use the `uncover` for blocks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{myFrame}{subtitle}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1->item 1
    \item<2->item 2
    \item<3->item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{block}<1->{Block1}
              Text in block 1.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}<2->{Block2}
          Text in block 2.
        \end{block}
        \begin{block}<3->{Block3}
          Text in block 3.
        \end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: Did you use the code of the answer?

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I found the error. In original dcument I had a list inside the list, and there I used `\pause`. That cause the problem. My bad. Thank you for clue. :)

Comment: @user31027: you're welcome `:)`. As a new user, I would courteously suggest for the future to upvote all answers you find useful, including those to others' questions and to check/accept the best answers to your own questions by clicking the green tick on the left-hand side of the answer. This will help the community.